# Fibonacci Sequence return argument

Tags: java

I need to generate a program that generates the Fibonacci Sequence
Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciRunner
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter n:");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        EP64 fg = new EP64();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            System.out.println(fg.nextNumber());
    }
}



public class EP64
{

    public static void nextNumber(int n)
    {
        int fold1 = 1;
        int fold2 = 1;
        int fnew = fold1 + fold2;        
        fold1 = fnew;
    }
}
```

I get an  error on:

```
    System.out.println(fg.nextNumber());
```

saying:
method nextNumber in class EP64 cannot be applied to given types:
required: int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

and can someone also tell me if I am doing this program right? If not, help! I looked at other similar questions but I cannot make much sense of them

Thank you all!

Comment: You need to spend a bit more time learning the language. Your `nextNumber` method doesn't return anything but requires an argument. You're calling it as if it returned something, and not giving it an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***method nextNumber in class EP64 cannot be applied to given types: required: int found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length***

Your

```
public static void nextNumber(int n)
                             ^^^^^^^
```

says that any call to the method must provide an integer as argument. But here:

```
System.out.println(fg.nextNumber());
                                ^^    you need to add an integer argument
```

you violate this by providing no argument.

As your code reads now, I'd probably drop the `int n` argument.

> ***and can someone also tell me if I am doing this program right?***

Naah, not really...

- `fold1` and `fold2` should probably be member variables (so they don't get reset in every call to the method),
- You're forgetting to update `fold2` (you only update `fold1`),
- Also, you probably want to return an `int` from the `nextNumber` method.

Read up on

- [Official Java Tutorial: Defining Methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Forgetting to update `fold2` doesn't matter as long as the two are reinitialised on each call ;)

Comment: Right. It does matter if he takes my first suggestion into account.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a static method to a object reference instead of the class itself.

And

Not passing any argument at all for nextNumber() method.

Make the method non-static as :

```
public void nextNumber(int n) {}
```

Pass arg to the method as :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        System.out.println(fg.nextNumber(n));
```

And also don't forget to return the processed number from your nextNumber method,which you collecting in System.out.println.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration of `nextNumber` says it takes an int argument, but you are calling it with no arguments.

Also, your code isn't going to do what you want. You probably should make `fold1` and `fold2` members of class EP64 and make the method an instance method rather than a static method. You also need to do `fold2 = fold1;` before you update `fold1`.

Finally, you need to declare `nextNumber` to return an int value, and then actually have it return an int value.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. Firstly, your method doesn't return anything, i.e. it is `void`.  You need to make it `int` and add a `return fnew;` at the end.  The other problem is you are starting from scratch every time, it will return `2` each time.  You need to make `fold1` and `fold2` fields by moving them above the `nextNumber` line. Oh, and drop the `int n` argument as it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

I agree on the diagnostics of the other posts, but don't suggest a member variable, but a rename and local variables.

You can ask for the 5th Fibonacci-Number with 5 calls to

```
fib.next ();
```

or with a single call to

```
fib (5);
```

Since the fibonacci-sequence increases very rapidly, you have very few calls (54) before hitting the overflow boundary. So if you repeatedly recalc the same sequence, to print the sequence, it's not a big problem. A recursive solution would be fine.

Btw.: EP64 is a very bad name.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is enough:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fibnocci
{    
public static void main(String []abc)
{
    int a=0,b=1,c;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the Range: ");
    int n= in.nextInt();
    System.out.print(a+" "+b);
    for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++) //n-2 because we are showing 0,1 initially.
    {
        c=a+b;
        System.out.print(" "+c);
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
}
}
```

If you want to call this as a method then:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Fibnocci
{    
public static void main(String []abc)
{        
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the Range: ");
    int n= in.nextInt();
    callFibonocci(n);
}
public static void callFibonocci(int n)
{
    int a=0,b=1,c;
    System.out.print(a+" "+b);
    for(int i=0;i<n-2;i++) //n-2 because we are showing 0,1 initially.
    {
        c=a+b;
        System.out.print(" "+c);
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }
}
}
```

You can call this method out of the class;

Answer (score 0):

//    Fibnocci Using c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CodeProject
{
    class FibnocciSeries
    {        
        public int[] FibonacciArray(int length)
        {
            int[] fseries = new int[length];

            fseries[0] = 0;
            fseries[1] = 1;

            if (length == 0)
                return null;

            //Iterating through the loup to add adjacent  numbers and create the memeber of series           
            for (int i = 2; i < length; i++)
            {
                fseries[i] = fseries[i - 1] + fseries[i - 2];
            }
            return fseries;
        }

    }
}

////////////////////

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            FibnocciSeries fb = new FibnocciSeries();
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Integer Length of Fibnocci series");
            int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] result = fb.FibonacciArray(length);

            foreach(int i in result)
                Console.Write(i.ToString()+ " ");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
|
```